# Periodically check if a folder has been deleted, using MSSQL SP + Command Line?

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, command-line, vbscript

I want to write an MSSQL Stored Procedure that periodically checks the filesystem it lives on to see if any folders have been deleted. It should work in an XP or Windows 7 environment.

I was thinking I might use the Windows Command Line or PowerShell (or VBScript) for this. I'll just call the script from the SQL Stored Procedure, it will check the filesystem, and then if a folder has been deleted it will alert the users.

My gut tells me there is a dead-simple solution for this somewhere. I know that matching directories is already a common task.

I've been playing with command line DIR and TREE, but so far they give me too much text. I really just want a simple list of folders that I can put into a small table in SQL. (I know that's overkill but it's what was requested.)

Comment: Show us what you have so far. And you're right, SQL sounds like overkill. Use a text file OR query your SQL table *from* VBscript, not the other way around.

Comment: To get a simple list of the subdirectories in a folder:  DIR /B /AD

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLEYOUCREATE] (
   [dir]  varchar(1000)
 , [diroutput]  varchar(1000)
)
GO

DECLARE @cmd varchar(8000)
SELECT @cmd = 'Dir "' + @path + '"'

INSERT INTO TABLEYOUCREATE(diroutput) EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```